# Assign values of a tuple to single variables in Scala

Tags: scala, tuples

is there a nice possibilyt to assign the values of a tuple to single variables? Here is what i want to do but it throws an error:

```scala
var a : Int = _
var b : Int = _

def init() {
   (a,b) = getTuple() // returns (Int, Int)
}

def someFunction = {    
    // use a here
}


def someOtherFunction = {    
    // use b here
}
```

```
Error: ';' expected but '=' found.
    (a, b) = getTuple()
```

Do i really have to do this ._1 and ._2 thing?

```scala
val tuple = getTuple() // returns (Int, Int)
a = tuple._1
b = tuple._2
```

Thanks for answering.

Comment: `val (a, b) = getTuple()` - Not need to use mutable variables.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez sorry, had to change the question. Do getTuple method has to run in another method... so this does not work.

Comment: Can you explain what are you doing? `vars` are a bad practice, specially uninitialized ones, also that name `init` sounds like a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [Section 6.15 *Assignments*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#assignments) of the Scala Language Specification, the lefthand-side of an assignment expression must be either a bare identifier:

```
foo = ???
// either an assignment to a local mutable `var` or syntactic sugar for:
foo_=(???)
```

a member access:

```
foo.bar = ???
// syntactic sugar for:
foo.bar_=(???)
```

or a method call:

```
foo(bar) = ???
// syntactic sugar for:
foo.update(bar, ???)
```

Pattern Matching is only available for value definitions (see [Section 4.1 *Value Declarations and Definitions*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions)) and variable definitions (see [Section 4.2 *Variable Declarations and Definitions*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#variable-declarations-and-definitions)).

So, both of the following would be legal:

```
var (a, b) = getTuple()
val (a, b) = getTuple()
```

By the way, there are a number of highly non-idiomatic things in your code:

- It is highly unusual to pass an empty argument list to a method call. Normally, methods that have no parameters should have no parameter lists instead of an empty parameter list. The only exception are methods that have side-effects, where the empty parameter list serves as kind of a "warning flag", but methods which have side-effects are highly non-idiomatic as well. So, `getTuple` should be defined and called like this:

  ```
  def getTuple = ???
  getTuple
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  def getTuple() = ???
  getTuple()
  ```
- On the other hand, if the method *does* have side-effects, it shouldn't be called `getTuple` because that implies that the method "gets" something, and there is no indication that it also *changes* something.
- In Scala, getters and setters are not called `getFoo` and `setFoo` but rather `foo` and `foo_=`, so the method should rather be called `tuple`.
- Mutable variables are highly non-idiomatic as well, they should probably rather be `val`s.

Answer (score 1):

Tuple destructuring is an opaque call to `unapply` method of `TupleN[T1, ..., Tn]` companion object, aka [extractor object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html).
As the documentation suggests, one can only have a variable initialization with an extractor object, but not assignment.

So, the only possible way is to use it like this:

```scala
def getTuple = (1,2)

def main() = {
    val (a,b) = getTuple
    // use a,b
}
```

The fact that you use a `var` may be the sign you have a design flaw. Try to refactor your code or specify the exact problem you're trying to solve with the `var` to justify its usage (although what you're trying to do with extractor is still impossible)